# Quotes and double quotes appear twice after keyboard press

Tags: keyboard

I have a keyboard that’s experiencing the following problem:

When I type `'` or `"`, it will not appear. When I press the key again, the `'` or `"` will appear twice.

The OS is Windows 10 Enterprise. The issue had been happening since this week.
The input language is “English US” so it is definitely not an issue with the language settings.

What is the possible cause of this issue?

Comment: Substitute a different keyboard as a test

Comment: Please update your question to provide more clarity as to what might be happening: What OS are you using? And has this issue just suddenly appeared? Or has it been happening for a while?

Answer (score 4):

Nevermind about the issue. I have discovered the fix to my problem. 
I just had the wrong keyboard layout. I had it set to United States-International instead of US.

Comment: If you use International, that's intentional - so you can type using dead-keys to add accents. Test using `'` followed by `e` as an example. If you don't want the next character to be accented, type a `space` instead [which won't add a space, just 'release' the character.]

Answer (score 1):

For Windows10:

- search `Language Setting`
- I assumed you have already selected the `English keyboard`, so if it is the United States, select the `Options`
- Under `Keyboard`, you will see `United States-International` (leave it as it is for now because until you add a new keyboard, you cannot remove it.
- Select the `+` key, and select the new `Keyboards`, just `US`
- Now remove the old keyboard, `United States-International`
- That's it!

Comment: The point of this answer will help some newbies like me in the future. I had a similar problem and googled led me here while the previous answer was not very clear. I re-modified and thought of future assistance, that is why StackOverflow is.